# Notificaciones para un portal web

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy empezando a crear un apartado sencillo para las notificaciones de un portal web, estas notificaciones serán cuando se agregue un comentario o se genere un nuevo tramite, pero me he topado con un problema el cual es el siguiente.
Tengo mi base de datos en la cual utilizo una tabla llamada notificaciones para hacer las consultas que se muestran en el código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
            $sqlNotif = "SELECT * FROM notificaciones WHERE contador = '1' GROUP BY id DESC";
            $resultNotif = mysqli_query($conexion, $sqlNotif);
            while ($verNotif = mysqli_fetch_row($resultNotif)) {
                $datos = $verNotif[0] . "||" .
                    $verNotif[1] . "||" .
                    $verNotif[2] . "||" .
                    $verNotif[3] . "||" .
                    $verNotif[4] . "||" .
                    $verNotif[5] . "||" .
                    $verNotif[6];

            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">

                        <small>

                            <?php
                            if ($verNotif[5] == "TRAMITE") {

                                echo $verNotif[2] . " generó un nuevo" . " $verNotif[5]" . " el día" . " $verNotif[4]" . " y le fue asignado el folio" . " $verNotif[1]";


                            } elseif ($verNotif[5] == "COMENTARIO") {
                                $sqlComent = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM notificaciones WHERE contador = '1' AND (folio = '$verNotif[1]' AND tipo = 'COMENTARIO') GROUP BY folio";
                                $resultComent = mysqli_query($conexion, $sqlComent);
                                while ($verComent = mysqli_fetch_row($resultComent)) {
                                    $coment = $verComent[0];
                                }
                                echo $verNotif[2] . " agrego" . " $coment" . " Comentario(s)" . " al folio" . " $verNotif[1]";

                            }
                            ?>

                        </small>
                    </td>
```

El problema radica cuando imprimo dichos resultados en el portal web, como se muestra en la imagen, es correcto que agregue 4 comentarios en un folio pero necesito agruparlos, es decir, que no se muestren de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si no que solo se muestre una sola vez, ejemplo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Declara la variable fuera del ciclo while, asignale el valor que mostrará dentro de dicho ciclo y luego imprimela por fuera para que solo salga una vez

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, solo tengo una duda, ¿de que variable estamos hablando?

Comment: En la que almacenes el texto de la notificación

Comment: Lo estoy poniendo como me lo comentas, al hacerlo pierdo los datos, ya no los muestra en la tabla.

Comment: SELECT * FROM notificaciones WHERE contador = '1' GROUP BY id DESC este query te esta devolviendo 4 registros...

Comment: Entones no entiendo tu problema.. si sabes que query te trae registros de mas, que queres hacer entonces?

Comment: El problema es cuando imprimo los resultados el el primer echo ya que ahí utilizo la matriz del primer while del código, no se si me estoy dando a entender.